# Problemas con la función

Tags: javascript, funciones

Buenas noches, estoy practicando un ejercicio pero me da un error al no reconocer una función y no logro detectarlo. Si me pueden ayudar a conseguirlo se los agradecería ya que soy novato en la programación y estoy aprendiendo javascript.
El código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prueba JavaScript</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Persona(nombre,edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.mayor = mayor;
    }

    function imprimirNombre() {
        document.write(this.nombre+" tiene "+this.edad);
    }

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var vector = new Array(4);
    vector[0] = new Persona("Juan","23");
    vector[1] = new Persona("Danilo","27");
    vector[2] = new Persona("Santiago","32");
    vector[3] = new Persona("Diego","19");

    var mayor=0;

    for(var i=1; i<vector.length; i++) {
        if (vector[i].edad>vector[mayor].edad) {
            mayor = i;
        }
    }

    document.write("Personas con mayor edad: <br>");
    for(var i=0; i<vector.length; i++) {
        if (vector[i].edad == vector[mayor].edad) {
            vector[i].imprimirNombre();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Los métodos deben estar dentro del objeto**

### En el prototpipo

```
Persona.prototype.imprimirNombre = function () {
    document.write(this.nombre+" tiene "+this.edad);
}
```

### En el constructor

```
function Persona(nombre,edad) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.mayor = mayor;
    this.imprimirNombre = function() {
        document.write(this.nombre+" tiene "+this.edad);
    }
}
```

Ambas funcionan y son casi iguales en lo que estás haciendo

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder..!

Comment: No es nada. Si te sirvió vota y/o acepta la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

En la funcion Persona estas haciendo que this.mayor=mayor pero sin embargo a la funcion no le pasas ningún parámetro mayor.

Comment: Si le pasó el valor, la suma me sirve de contador, lo que ocurre es que no había declarado la función imprimirNombre